# lower first letter of column by keeping rest as it is

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data is like

users table:

```
ID       Name          Address
1        Shane         England
2        Mark          NewZeaLand
3        Andrew        Jordon
```

I want to update address in users table like newZeaLand.

here is what i have tried
but it is lowering all letters as lower case

```
update users  
set Address=lower(Address)  
where ID=2
```

Comment: Hint: `SUBSTRING()`.

Comment: @jarlh can you show me a sample

Comment: @PhxDev, rather the opposite, but not exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
update users  
    set Address = lower(substr(address, 1, 1)) || substr(address, 2)
    where ID = 2;
```